# integration of $\int_0^\infty\frac{(\log(x))^3}{x^3-1}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I have this integral to solve with complex analysis:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{(\log(x))^3}{x^3-1}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

My result is

$$\frac{\pi^3}{54}$$

But I don't know if it is ok..and so I ask you if it is.
Thanks

Comment: Integrating from where to where?

Comment: Ups...From $0$ to $+\infty$

Comment: So...is it + or - in the denominator?!

Comment: In the denominator there is -

Comment: Well, then please edit your question's title and fix it...!

Comment: Ok, so you say you did it and got that result...how did you do it? Show your work.

Comment: Well, I have calculate the same integral, but in this version

Comment: If you want us to check your work, you have to **show** your work. The final result is not particularly interesting. It's the way you get there that matters.

Comment: @CosmicVane , you mean you calculated that integral without complex analysis? How?! Anyway, however you did it, show your work.

Answer (score 6):

We can proceed as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/301725) and use the same contour.

First we will evaluate
$$
\int_\gamma\frac{\log^3(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag{1}
$$
over the contour

$\hspace{4.5cm}$[image]

Accounting for the pole at $e^{\pi i/3}$ with residue $\dfrac{(\pi i/3)^3}{3e^{2\pi i/3}}$ and letting $\alpha=e^{2\pi i/3}$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
2\pi i\dfrac{(\pi i/3)^3}{3e^{2\pi i/3}}
&=\color{#C00000}{\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^3(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z}
\color{#0000FF}{-\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^3(\alpha z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}\alpha z}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^3(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&-\alpha\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^3(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z
-3\frac{2\pi i}{3}\alpha\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^2(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&+3\frac{4\pi^2}{9}\alpha\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z
+\frac{8\pi^3 i}{27}\alpha\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Multiplying by $\alpha$, noting that $\alpha(1-\alpha)=2i\sin(\pi/3)=i\sqrt3$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{2\pi^4}{81}
&=i\sqrt3\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^3(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z
-2\pi i\alpha^2\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^2(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&+\frac{4\pi^2}{3}\alpha^2\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z
+\frac{8\pi^3 i}{27}\alpha^2\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
The real part of $(3)$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{2\pi^4}{81}
&=-\pi\sqrt3\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^2(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z
-\frac{2\pi^2}{3}\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z
+\frac{4\pi^3\sqrt3}{27}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=-\pi\sqrt3\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^2(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z
-\frac{2\pi^2}{3}\left(-\frac{2\pi^2}{27}\right)
+\frac{4\pi^3\sqrt3}{27}\left(\frac{2\pi\sqrt3}{9}\right)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
where we used the result of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/301725). Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^2(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\frac{10\pi^3\sqrt3}{243}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
The imaginary part of $(3)$ is
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\sqrt3\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^3(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z
+\pi\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^2(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&-\frac{2\pi^2\sqrt3}{3}\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z
-\frac{4\pi^2}{27}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\sqrt3\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^3(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z
+\pi\left(\frac{10\pi^3\sqrt3}{243}\right)\\
&-\frac{2\pi^2\sqrt3}{3}\left(-\frac{2\pi^2}{27}\right)
-\frac{4\pi^2}{27}\left(\frac{2\pi\sqrt3}{9}\right)\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
where we used the result of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/301725) and $(4)$. Therefore,
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^3(z)}{z^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}z=-\frac{14\pi^4}{243}\tag{7}
$$

---

Next we will evaluate
$$
\int_\gamma\frac{\log^3(z)}{z^3-1}\tag{8}
$$
over the contour

$\hspace{6cm}$[image]

Noting that there are no poles inside the contour and letting $\beta=e^{\pi i/3}$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\color{#C00000}{\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^3(x)}{x^3-1}\,\mathrm{d}x}
\color{#0000FF}{-\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^3(\beta x)}{-x^3-1}\,\mathrm{d}\beta x}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^3(x)}{x^3-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&+\beta\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^3(x)}{x^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}x
+3\frac{\pi i}{3}\beta\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^2(x)}{x^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&-3\frac{\pi^2}{9}\beta\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}x
-\frac{\pi^3i}{27}\beta\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^3(x)}{x^3-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&+\beta\left(-\frac{14\pi^4}{243}\right)
+\pi i\beta\left(\frac{10\pi^3\sqrt3}{243}\right)\\
&-\frac{\pi^2}{3}\beta\left(-\frac{2\pi^2}{27}\right)
-\frac{\pi^3i}{27}\beta\left(\frac{2\pi\sqrt3}{9}\right)\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^3(x)}{x^3-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&+\left(\frac12\right)\left(-\frac{14\pi^4}{243}\right)
+\pi\left(-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)\left(\frac{10\pi^3\sqrt3}{243}\right)\\
&-\frac{\pi^2}{3}\left(\frac12\right)\left(-\frac{2\pi^2}{27}\right)
-\frac{\pi^3}{27}\left(-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)\left(\frac{2\pi\sqrt3}{9}\right)\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^3(x)}{x^3-1}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{16\pi^4}{243}\tag{10}
$$

Comment: I'm impressed that you bothered to type all that, especially considering that the OP didn't care enough to answer the questions that were asked of him

Comment: @mrf: well, I've done a couple of these before, so I knew how to go. What's more depressing is that this answer will only be read by a few people.