# Evaluate integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{1+x^3}dx$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I can't seem to evaluate this integral

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log (x)}{1+x^3}\, dx$$

No matter what I do, I tried every method I can think of but nothing works, I tried substituting $x$ with mutiple thing, integration by parts...
I tried using the app called WolframAlpha and it says that my integral evaluates to $-\frac{2\pi^2}{27}$, but it doesn't show the step-by-step process.
Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Contour integration seems likely

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/301573/815585

Answer (score 4):

An elementary solution

\begin{align}\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x^3+1}{d}x
= &
\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)\ln x}{x^3+1}{d}x 
=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x+1}{d}x
 - \int_0^1{\frac{x^2\ln x}{x^3+1}} \overset{x^3\to x}{dx}\\
=&\> \left(1-\frac19\right)\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x+1}{d}x
=\frac89\left(-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right)
=-\frac{2\pi^2}{27}
\end{align}

where [$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x+1}{d}x=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3826136/686284)

Comment: The question is a duplicate.

Comment: @Gary - I’m not sure. OP does not ask for contour integration

Comment: You are right. This is a marginal case.

Answer (score 3):

We shall just use an elementary well-known result for which you can find several proofs involving the beta function or Ramanujan’s master theorem:

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{x^n+1} \, dx=\frac{\pi}{n} \csc\left(\frac{\pi s}{n}\right)$$

Take $n=3$ and the partial derivative with respect to $s$:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1} \ln x}{x^3+1}\, dx=-\frac{\pi^2}{9} \cot \left(\frac{\pi s}{3}\right)\csc\left(\frac{\pi s}{3}\right)$$

Taking $s\to 1$ gives the required result:

$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^3+1} \, dx=-\frac{2\pi^2}{27}}$$

Comment: can you link me to a proof of the result you used?

Comment: @SayanDutta See [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634091/generalisation-of-an-already-generalised-integral?noredirect=1)